# Minimize SQLite library size

Tags: sqlite

I assume this is the same for sqlite3.dll or sqlite3.lib, but if not, I am interested in sqlite3.o (mingw32).

How can I minimize the size of the library (compiling with `-O3`, since speed is my top concern, so different compiler optimizations is not an option)?
If I know there are parts of SQL I don't need in my program (like `JOIN` or `ATTACH` or triggers), can I remove support for them (this is for an embedded system and every byte counts, or at least every 100 bytes or so)?
What pre-processor  options can I set to remove things like FTS or R-Tree support which I do not need? Do I set them at the command line or in the file?
Are there any other things easily removable that I might not need and might not even know they exist in order to remove them?
How about some of the C API? Most of it I never use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html). There's a chapter "Options to omit features". You'll find for example `SQLITE_OMIT_ATTACH` there.

But please note the warning there. It says

> the SQLITE_OMIT_* compile-time options are usually untested and are
>   almost certainly untested in combination. Any or all of these options
>   may be removed from the code in future releases and without warning.
>   For any particular release, some of these options may cause
>   compile-time or run-time failures, particularly when used in
>   combination with other options.